# How can I monitor syslog and send notification based on events?

Tags: monitoring, syslog, events, rsyslog

I'm going to be sending syslog from my one device/server to an Ubuntu server.

On the Ubuntu server (receiving the syslog), I want it to trigger a script when specific syslog messages arrive.

Is this possible?

Comment: "send notification" and "trigger a script" is not quite the same. Could you be more specific to what the requirements are and/or what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I'm trying to send a notification to XBMC which can be sent by executing a pre-existing shell script or sending an HTTP request to the XBMC server.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Question seems to have changed a bit and targetted on scripting, rather than sending notifications. I might remove this answer later.</sup>

<sup>It seems it is [quite straightforward](http://www.arix.com/docs/rsyslog-3.22.1/rsyslog_conf.html) to set up real time triggering of shell scripts based on messages passed to rsyslog. If OP rewrites his answer to contain a better picture of what he is aiming for (as already posted in comments), I am willing to provide a high quality answer here.</sup>

Not exactly sure what your requirements are, but one particular piece of software I could recommend is [`logcheck`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/logcheck). This may be useful in your situation too.

Its purpose is to send mail digests on specific matched (interesting) lines. I'm assuming basic mail configuration is working (e.g. `echo bla | mail -s testmail user@domain.tld` works) already. It takes care of log rotations and it knows where it has left of, so don't worry about that in scripting anymore!

Extracted some of the essential steps from [this tutorial](http://stackful.io/blog/keep-an-eye-on-your-linux-servers-with-logcheck/):

1. Configure basic things in `/etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf`:

   ```
   REPORTLEVEL="server"          # default reportlevel with pre-configured filters
   SENDMAILTO="user@domain.tld"
   ```
2. Which log files to check in `/etc/logcheck/logcheck.logfiles`:

   ```
   /var/log/syslog
   /var/log/auth.log
   /var/log/myapp.log
   ```
3. Now, to tell it to trigger on a specific line similar to

   ```
   myapp: Error: Login failed for admin123
   ```

   for this myapp log, this can be realized by creating a regular expression in `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/myapp` (note `server` corresponding to the used `REPORTLEVEL` earlier on):

   ```
   ^myapp:.*
   ```

   <sub>Okay, this is not the most specific regex, but that's not the point.</sub>
4. Wait emails to arrive, e.g.:

   ```
   Subject: webserver.domain.tld 2013-01-01 10:17 System Events

   Jan 01 09:40:59 webserver myapp: IMAP Error: Login failed for gertvdijk
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  What's actually happening is that my VOIP adapter is sending Caller ID information via syslog to another PC.  When I see this information, I need to execute a shell script or send an HTTP command to XBMC (media player) to display the incoming caller id.

Comment: @SofaKng Okay. Well, interesting use case, but that kind of information should be part of your answer.

Comment: `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server` Does not tell it to trigger, it tells it to ignore. By default, you get a firehose of everything, not a whitelist.