# Error during "Running newaliases"

Tags: software-installation, postfix

I need some help with this please.

**I started here as mentioned:** in this post [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235868/how-can-i-monitor-syslog-and-send-notification-based-on-events/691848#691848)

```
nitapika@nitapika-51:~$ echo bla | mail -s testmail lisa@you5.com

The program 'mail' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

**Then installed mailutils:** and received this error

```
Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 04
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mydomain: bad parameter value: 04
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 75
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailutils:
 mailutils depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides default-mta is not configured yet.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mailutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
 mailutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

nitapika@nitapika-51:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload

[....] Reloading postfix configuration (via systemctl): postfix.serviceJob for postfix.service invalid.
 failed!
```

**Then tried:**

```
nitapika@nitapika-51:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up postfix (2.11.3-1ubuntu2) ...

Postfix configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 04
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mydomain: bad parameter value: 04
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 75
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailutils:
 mailutils depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides default-mta is not configured yet.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mailutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
 mailutils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**And then:**

```
nitapika@nitapika-51:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow postfix
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: postfix is broken or not fully installed
```

Not sure how to fix this. I only need the logcheck app to send me abnormalities.

Comment: I was getting a similar error which seemed to be due to an bug. A fix is explained [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/1931801).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Correct `mydomain` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

   `04` is not a valid domain name - a valid value is an entry of the tour `domain.tld`.
2. Change the value for `valid_hostname` as well.

   This is only a warning but hostnames are not numeric - use the output of

   ```
    hostname --fqdn
   ```

After that execute:

```
sudo newaliases
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

```
mydomain

    The internet domain name of this mail system. The default is to use
    $myhostname minus the first component, or "localdomain" (Postfix 2.3 
    and later). $mydomain is used as a default value for many other
    configuration parameters.

myhostname

    The internet hostname of this mail system. The default is to use the
    fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) from gethostname(), or to use the
    non-FQDN result from gethostname() and append ".$mydomain".$myhostname
    is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters.
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the email issue. Now on to the logcheck setup.

Comment: I tried to test  by running: sudo -u logcheck logcheck -o -t
and received error:   Oct 30 16:42:26 rotaderp gnome-session[2756]: Could not locate Tomboy on D-Bus. Perhaps it's not running?
Oct 30 16:42:26 rotaderp gnome-session[2756]: [Error 16:42:26.406] [UniverseManager] Error while updating item source "Torrents": Cannot access Transmission RPC service
Oct 30 16:42:26 rotaderp gnome-session[2756]: [Error 16:42:26.769] [UniverseManager] Error while updating item source "Firefox Places": Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
Should Tomboy be installed?

Comment: You have two completely different problems. I have solved the main problem. The other question is too specific. Ask a new question for this problem. Please accept this answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason `sudo apt-get install -f` keeps changing the configuration in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to some invalid crap `myserver.168.1.25` so install fails all time miserably. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First know your hostname using command:

```
hostname
```

Edit ***/etc/postfix/main.cf*** file by using:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Now, change:

```
myhostname =
```

to

```
myhostname = your_hostname #name of your hostname
```

Now reboot your system and run:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Type the following command in the terminal:

```
$ postconf -d myhostname
```

Now edit the ***/etc/postfix/main.cf*** file by changing the `myhostname` to the hostname you got by executing the previous command. i.e change:

```
myhostname = new_hostname
```

Here, `new_hostname` is your hostname obtained executing the command `$ postconf -d myhostname`

After changing the file, save it and run the following commands:

```
$ /etc/init.d/postfix reload
$ service postfix reload
```