# Error while installing postfix

Tags: apt, email, postfix

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

gives the following issue:

```
Setting up postfix (3.1.0-3ubuntu0.3) ...

Postfix configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: timber..name
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: timber..name
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I looked up other similar posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691903/error-during-running-newaliases#) and the error seems to be the '..'in the hostname but whenever I remove it and change the name to 
*timber*, reload it and then retry installing postfix, it reverts the name back to *timber..name* and I get the same error again.

```
Setting up postfix (3.1.0-3ubuntu0.3) ...
setting myhostname=timber..name in /etc/postfix

Postfix is now set up with the changes above.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: timber..name
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: timber..name
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm not sure how to permanantly change the name or in any case to remove the error. Now, whenever I try to install any package I get errors because of postfix.

Answer (score 2):

- Run `sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Find the line `hostname =`
- Change it:

**From:**
`myhostname = timber..name`
**To:**
`myhostname = timber.name` (ie. remove the extra dot, instead of both)

Finally, run `sudo apt install --fix-broken`
Hope it helps.